# Can I save the coordinates for a UMAP embedding?

Tags: python, dimensionality-reduction, runumap

I am running a UMAP model as follows:

```
    embedding = umap.UMAP(n_components=2,n_neighbors=30, min_dist=0.0, metric='euclidean').fit(data)
```

And plotting:

```
    f = umap.plot.points(embedding, labels=df['name'])
```

This generates a nice looking graph. I'd like to get the coordinates of the points plotted, to move to a different visualisation. I don't fully understand what is stored in        the embedding object.

Is there a way I can export to something like:

```
    [{'name': name1, 'x-value': x1, 'y-value': y1}, {'name': name2, 'x-value': x2, 'y-value': y2 }...]
```

Or similar?

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of the x,y coordinates by doing

```
    embedding.embedding_
```

Not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a DataFrame with coordinates, add a column with the names, and turn it into a list of dicts.

It seems like you already have a DataFrame with the column `name`. If that's the case, I'd go for something like:

```
import pandas as pd

# Add coordinates into a Df
df_c = pd.DataFrame(embedding.embedding_)

# Add column with names
df_c['name'] = df['name']

# Transform Df into list of dicts
df_c.to_dict('records')
```